# How To Create A Message Box From Google App Script To Web App

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, web-applications, message

I'm trying to create a message box from my .gs to my web app, I tried these but the message box couldn't show up:

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('View');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');

Browser.msgBox('Hello!', Browser.Buttons.OK);

HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hello!");
```

Are those methods the right way to do it? Your response will be appreciated :)

Comment: When you say Web Page, doy you mean that you try to mbedd this code in a WebApp? Please provide more context / code if possible.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I mean Web App

Comment: Where is this webapp?

Comment: @TheMaster I just wanna create a message box from my .gs, should I also post my html code?

Comment: @Ray context. Step back. How is the function called? And from where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The methods you are trying to use are designed for [use in the context of a Google Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser)

- You cannot use them within a WebApp, even if your WebApp is bound to a spreadsheet.
- It would make little sense anyway, since when you deploy a WebApp, you interact with the WebApp interface, not with the spreadsheet UI.
- Instead you need to use Javascript methods that are accessible from the clientside of your WebApp, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp).

**Sample:**

*Code.js*

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
}


function called(){
  
  Logger.log("I was called");
  //the rest of your code
}
```

*index.html*

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    if (confirm("Please confirm, are you sure you want to continue?")) {
     alert( "google.script.run will be called");
     google.script.run.called();
   } else {
    alert( "You cancelled!");
   } 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```